# JQ | concatenate commands

Tags: pipeline, jq

Is there a way I can concatenate these js's command in just one jq command?

```
jq 'map({a: .children[1].text, f: .children[0].text})' | \
jq 'map(select(.a != null))' | \
jq 'map(select(.f != null))' | \
jq 'map([.a, [.f,(.f | length)]])' | \
jq -c '.[]'
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Probably. What does your input look like, and what should the output look like? To a first approximation, you just connect the filters themselves: `jq  -c 'map(...) | map(...) | map (...) | map (...) | . []'`.

Comment: It worked just fine! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jq -c '.[]
| {a: .children[1].text, f: .children[0].text}
| select(.a != null)
| select(.f != null)
| [.a, [.f,(.f | length)]]'`